# False expression in if condition goes true

Tags: java

I studied the **Conditions** material today and got some homework, some of them are pretty easy and some of them are tricky to implement. 
However, I got this following code:

```
boolean bool1, bool2, bool3;
bool1 = false;
bool2 = true;
bool3 = true;
    if(bool1 == true || bool2 == true && bool3 == true)
        System.out.println("true");
    else
        System.out.println("false");
```

I don't understand why this program returning `true` while there's a **false** statement - `bool1` is declared as FALSE in the beginning of the program, and when it's checked (`bool1 == true`) the **if** should return false.

Comment: The test in the conditional statement is not limited to `bool1`. Try to recall what you have learned about boolean operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break this down a bit :

```
bool1 == true // FALSE : because bool1 has the value of "false"
bool2 == true // TRUE : because bool2 has a value of "true"
bool3 == true // TRUE : because bool2 has a value of "true"
```

Let's go back to the expression and replace :

```
(FALSE || TRUE && TRUE)
```

`FALSE || ...` : Since it is a `||` and the first value is `false`, we have to check the second value.

`TRUE && ...` : Now we're checking the second value, since it is `true` and we are using `&&`, we have to check the second expression. Since in this case it is `true`, the whole expression becomes `TRUE`

---

### More Information

[Wiki's Page for Boolean Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_expression)

Answer (score 1):

**The problem is in the following line:**

`if(bool1 == true || bool2 == true && bool3 == true)`

In this statement you're asking for two conditions:

1. `Bool1 == true` OR
2. `Bool2 == true && Bool3 == true`.

As you might have mentioned `||` means 'OR'.
In you're code you have declared both `Bool2` and `Bool3` as `true`. So the second condition in the if-statement is correct and will cause the block to continue, which in your case will print `True`.

> **What I think you're trying to do is the following:**
>
> 1. `Bool1` OR `Bool2` (or both) is/are true. AND
> 2. `Bool3` is true.
>
> In that case you'll have to use the following code:
>
> ```
> if((bool1 == true || bool2 == true) && bool3 == true)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(bool1 == true || bool2 == true && bool3 == true)
            System.out.println("true");
```

The above if statement says, if either bool1 or bool2 is true, and if bool3 is true print me **"true"**

> Read more about || operator.

The above operator means, atleast one should be true out of two expressions.

&&, all expressions must be true.
||, atleast one is enough.

Answer (score 0):

|| stand for OR. If the left or the right side of OR is TRUE then the result is TRUE . The  right side is TRUE and this is why you get the result TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

> if(bool1 == true || bool2 == true && bool3 == true)

`&&` is prior to `||` , so `bool2 == true && bool3 == true` is evaluated first (== `true`). The condition becomes:

> if(bool1 == true || true)

which evaluates to `true` also. Hence you get "true" as output.

Comment: _bool2 == true && bool3 == true_ is not evaluated first. `&&` just has higher precedence.

Comment: Read carefully what I said (&& is prior to ||). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: Taken literally from your question: _so bool2 == true && bool3 == true is evaluated first_ That is a false statement. What does _prior_ mean?

Comment: Here, check this link for a clear explanation : http://www.phrasemix.com/phrases/prior-to-something

Comment: Then your answer is still wrong. Java evaluates statements left to right. Operator precedence has no bearing on evaluation order.

Comment: This is what Meta is made for.

Comment: What? No. I'm not going to post to meta to explain that your answer, as stated, is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The condition returns true because of the OR operator: ||.
 This operator returns true if at least one of the two expressions next to it is true. In your case, you have true or false, therefore true.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `||` means 'or' and `&&` means 'and'. So basically in your case, if `bool1` OR `bool2` are true, the condition is correct. Try your code changing the value of `bool2`to `false` aswell, and you will see that the program will return you a `false` statement.